# Query SQL Table And Store Results In Array

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ado

I am wanting to query a SQL Server Table and store the results from that query in an array.  I am only returning a `Distinct()` from one field so it should be pretty straight forward.  My syntax produces the error

> Invalid Qualifier

On this line of code `Set r = conn.Execute` and it highlights the word `conn` How should I re-write this syntax to still use `ADO` but be able to successfully run this procedure?

```
Public Function ReturnData()
Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
Dim f As ADODB.Field
Dim conn As String
Dim arrResults() As Variant
Set c = New ADODB.Connection
With c
.Provider = "sqloledb.1"
With .Properties
    .Item("Data Source") = "ServerName"
    .Item("Initial Catalog") = "Database"
    .Item("PassWord") = "password"
    .Item("User ID") = "user"
End With
.Open
Set r = conn.Execute("SELECT Distinct(Name) from registered where cancelled IS NULL;")
i = 0
r.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
    arrResults(i) = rst.Fields(0)
    i = i + 1
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
c.Close
End Function
```

Comment: you've got conn is a string there, c is a connection - can you do c.execute

Comment: There are a few problems with this code.  Did you copy/paste this from the internet?  There are a several occasions where you call on the variable `rst`.  But this isn't defined.  Suspect you should replace with `r`.  There two with statements.  But only 1 'End With'.  The variable i is not declared.  `Dim i AS Integer` to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've got conn is a string there, c is a connection - can you do c.execute

try

```
Set r = c.Execute(...
```

I'm not sure if you need a command object, if you do, then see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

to see how to make a command for your connection and execute it

Anyhow, at the moment you are trying to 'execute' on a string - string is a primitive type and does not execute on the DB - I think you just mixed c and conn up - let us know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get a recordset into an array is to use `Split` and `Recordset.GetString`. It avoids the loop anyway. Here's an example.

```
Public Sub RsToArray()

    Dim adoCon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim adoRs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim vaLocations As Variant

    Set adoCon = New ADODB.Connection
    adoCon.Open sConn
    Set adoRs = adoCon.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT LocationName FROM Locations")

    vaLocations = Split(adoRs.GetString, vbCr)

    Debug.Print Join(vaLocations, "|")

    adoRs.Close
    adoCon.Close

    Set adoRs = Nothing
    Set adoCon = Nothing

End Sub
```